# Can Strapi handle 1.5 million products and 30k categories with a depth of 6?

Tags: strapi, headless, saleor

Can Strapi handle 1.5 million products and 30,000 categories with a category depth of 6?

Hello guys,

I am considering using Strapi for my e-commerce project, and I would like to know if it can handle my specific use case. I have around 1.5 million products distributed across nearly 30,000 different categories. The depth of the category structure is 5 levels deep.

My questions are:

Can Strapi efficiently handle this large number of products and categories without any significant performance issues?

Are there any known limitations or issues when dealing with such a large and complex category structure in Strapi?

Are there any recommendations or best practices for managing this scale of products and categories with Strapi ?

I would greatly appreciate your insights and advice on whether Strapi is suitable for this use case. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Best regards, Francois

We are contemplating using Strapi but need to implement a detailed structured with a very large set of categories and sub-categories (ie 30k in total), with a depth of 6.

We would like to know if such a depth is native in Strapi (it is not the case in other CMS like Saleor, so we would need to make long and expensive developments to do so) or if there are special plug-ins to make it possible with reasonable efforts. Details of possible or examples of sites really appreciated !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every project is different but Strapi should be a good fit: https://www.rd.nl/ manages 1M articles with Strapi - https://strapi.io/user-stories/smartshore-ability-rd-nl

The best option is to create a Strapi project and inject lot of data into it through scripts.

Comment: thanks, the structure really differs while compared to our needs though, since we need to have a depth of 6!